# How can I avoid obtaining loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00 for CNN-LSTM?

Tags: keras, nan, loss

I am trying to make 3 class classification with CNN-LSTM, I have prepared my data on MATLAB, and train with the following code. It works for binary classification, where I used binary cross entropy, but does not work for multi class case I used sparse_categorical_crossentropy. I am having nan for loss and 0.0000e+00 for accuracy. What is wrong here?

```
import os 
os.environ["CUDA_DEVİCE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
 os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"  

import scipy.io 
import numpy as np 
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('frames3class_train80_test20.mat')
 XTrain = mat['tensortrain'] 
y = mat['YTrain']  
## trainlength=2400 
X = np.zeros(shape=(trainlength,8,18,400,1))
 X[:,:,:,:,0]=XTrain  
 import keras  from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Flatten, TimeDistributed, Conv2D, Dropout,MaxPooling2D 
from keras.models import Sequential 
width = 18 
height = 400 
kernelsize =2 
numberOfHiddenUnits =8 
model = Sequential() 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(2, (kernelsize, kernelsize), activation='relu'),                           input_shape=(None, width, height, 1)))
 model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten())) 
model.add(LSTM(numberOfHiddenUnits)) 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) 
opt=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.000001) model.compile(loss=keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=opt, metrics=['acc']) print(model.summary())  

model.fit(X, y,batch_size=16,epochs=30)
```

The result on the Python console is as

```
  16/2400 [..............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
  80/2400 [>.............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
 144/2400 [>.............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
 208/2400 [=>............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
 272/2400 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
 336/2400 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
 384/2400 [===>..........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: nan - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Thanks for the help,

Comment: 3 class classification with 1 output neuron and sigmoid activation

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed the labels with one hot encoding, and the loss function accordingly it is solved.